# Can't contact our Azure-AKS kube - TLS handshake timeout

Tags: azure-container-service

Since last friday (9th) we can't contact our AKS-kube using 'kubectl'.
All commands (get nodes, version, cluster-info, apply etc) results in a

> 'Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout'

```
$ curl -v hostname
* Rebuilt URL to: https://HOSTNAME.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io:443/
*   Trying NN.NN.NN.NN...
* Connected to HOSTNAME.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io (NN.NN.NN.NN) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 592 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
 (waiting for almost a minute)
* gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
```